# I am searching a roadmap to operate a robotic arm simulation

Tags: python, ros, moveit

https://github.com/EuropeanRoverChallenge/ERC-Remote-Maintenance-Sim

I used this link and I downloaded the simulation and it works on RViz with several errors. However it looks seamless.

However I don't know how to operate the robotic arm autonomously. I have ROS and Python basics, so how can I find a roadmap? Starting some fundamental movements will be able to useful.

Comment: As mentioned in [github](https://github.com/EuropeanRoverChallenge/ERC-Remote-Maintenance-Sim#control-the-robot) this robotic arm is controlled using [`Moveit` so you probably want to start here](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials) and [here seems to be tutorial on how to interact with Moveit using python](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_python_interface/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

That repository creates a docker package, then installs 3 other repositories inside:

1. https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot.git
2. https://github.com/roboticsgroup/roboticsgroup_gazebo_plugins
3. https://github.com/Michal-Bidzinski/UR3_sim.git

None of them seams to automate the motion, they are used to simulate and control the manipulator, but you still need to define the tasks and trajectories.

Comment: Is this meaning that all necessary things are ready, but I have to still write my own codes to operate them?

Comment: Either that or find an other package that does that for you.